# PHP Mysqli with hyphen

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query problem with hyphen character in search word.

```
$name = "%{$name}%";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `topic` WHERE `title` LIKE '$name'";
```

Variable `$name` like this `%Preacher - first%` dynamically.

But if it is dynamic this doesn't work. If I use like text, this doesn't work.

Comment: it should fixed for you $query = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE title LIKE '%$name%'";

Comment: why you put {} sign?

Comment: Don`t work, the problem is not this.

Comment: @muldy comment from Fahrudin should work check for "Preacher - first" string exists in your database or not.

Comment: I now that is work, but in my in my case, this don`t work. And where is problem I don`t know! String is exist. May be this is in config server problem? Or mysql?

Comment: %Preacher - first%, i think space is problem. not hyphen

Comment: No space is not problem!

Answer (score 0):

try with `htmlspecialchars();` function.

it should fixed for you,

`$query = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE title LIKE '%htmlspecialchars($name)%'";`